# How to push data to local JSON file on button click using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, web

index.html

`<button click="submit_data" id="submit">Submit</button>`

script.js

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
    task = document.getElementById('new_task').value
    task_deadline = document.getElementById('task_deadline').value
    let push_data = {
        "item": task,
        "deadline": task_deadline
    }
    // FileSystem.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(push_data));
})
```

I have a json file in the same directory and I am trying to push `push_data` to that file, but I cannot seem to find a solution.
I am not using any framework such as Angular or React.
Is it possible using plain javascript?
If not, what are the possible solutions?

Comment: FileSystem.writeFileSync("data.json", JSON.stringify(push_data));

Comment: @Suresh _"This interface will not grant you access to the users filesystem. Instead you will have a "virtual drive" within the browser sandbox."_ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the API designed for this purposes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API#writing_to_files

```
async function saveFile(blob) {
  // create a new handle
  const newHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker();
  // create a FileSystemWritableFileStream to write to
  const writableStream = await newHandle.createWritable();
  // write our file
  await writableStream.write(blob);
  // close the file and write the contents to disk.
  await writableStream.close();
}

function save () {
    let push_data = {
        "item": "test",
        "deadline": "test2"
    }
    saveFile(JSON.stringify(push_data)).then(console.log).catch(console.error); 
}

save();
```

Note:

> This API opens up potential functionality the web has been lacking. Still, security has been of utmost concern when designing the API, and access to file/directory data is disallowed unless the user specifically permits it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a URL to download. A dataURL. See also [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/itgoldman/djuy5x30/1/)

```js
var storageObj = {
  "hello": "world"
}

function download_json() {
  var dataStr = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(storageObj));
  var dlAnchorElem = document.querySelector('.dummy');
  dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("href", dataStr);
  dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("download", "scene.json");
  dlAnchorElem.click();
}
```

```html
Click to download JSON on a non-sandbox environment 
<form onsubmit="download_json(); return false">
  <button click="submit_data" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<a class="dummy"></a>
```